# Convert data.frame objects to zoo objects

Tags: r

I am trying to convert data.frame objects to zoo (zoo package) objects. The first step in doing that is to convert a date column in my data (df) into Date class using `as.Date` with the format D/M/Y. The data looks like:

```
Date          Return
1986-02-03     0.10
1986-02-04     0.15
1986-02-05     0.16
1986-02-06     0.18
```

When using the following code:

```
df.data <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

it converts to the class but dates are on Y-M-D format. When using the following code

```
df.data <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

it give NA of all values. Where is the problem?

Sys: Mavericks 64bit

Comment: Wouldn't this creates zoo object `zoo(df[,2],as.Date(df$Date))`  If you want to format the dates you could use `zoo(df[,2], format(as.Date(df$Date), "%d/%m/%y"))`

Comment: Yes it would. The issue I have is with the as.Date with format option. I tried yours; the first one works fine but the second one gives NA for all dates. @akrun

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the NA's.  I posted as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `read.zoo`:

```
z <- read.zoo(DF)
```

**Note:** We assumed `DF` is:

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = c("1986-02-03", "1986-02-04", "1986-02-05", "1986-02-06"), 
                 Return = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.16, 0.18))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("1986-02-03", "1986-02-04", "1986-02-05", 
"1986-02-06"), Return = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.16, 0.18)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Return"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

library(zoo)
 zoo(df[,2], format(as.Date(df$Date), "%d/%m/%y"))
#03/02/86 04/02/86 05/02/86 06/02/86 
#   0.10     0.15     0.16     0.18 

zoo(df[,2],as.Date(df$Date))
#1986-02-03 1986-02-04 1986-02-05 1986-02-06 
#   0.10       0.15       0.16       0.18
```